# args.join not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

exports.exec = async (message, args) => {
    const text = args.join(" "); /* RIGHT HERE IS THE PROBLEM */
    const url = `https://public-api.tracker.gg/apex/v1/standard/profile/5/${text}`;
    const options = {
        headers: {
            'TRN-Api-Key': `${credentials.apexAPIKey}`
        }
    };

    if (args[0] != 'set')
        axios
            .get(url, options)
            .then(stats => {
                stats.data.data.stats.map(stat => {
                    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                        .setColor(0)
                        .setTitle(`Apex Legends Stats For ${stats.data.data.metadata.platformUserHandle}`)
                        .addField(stat.metadata.name, `${stat.value} ${stat.percentile ? '(Top ' + stat.percentile + '%)' : ''}`)
                    return message.channel.send({ embed });
                })
            })

};
```

I know this question has appeared multiple times around here, I've attempted to go through them and try alternate methods but all have failed. So I'm asking the question myself, line 2 is the problem.

`TypeError: args.join is not a function`

`at Object.module.exports.exec (C:\Users\goose\Downloads\Peeps\commands\player-stats\apexlegends.js:5:23)`

I don't have a clue, and I hate having to ask here but I'm beyond stumped. Works in other commands happily with the same setup basically, here in this command, it hates me. Only 2 commands throw back this error currently, whilst other commands with `args.join (" ");` are living their little happy life.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try turning args into a array before calling `join`. For example `Array.from(args).join()` but if `args` is a string you could actually do not need to

Comment: I think you need to add the rest operator `exports.exec = async (message, ...args) => {`

Comment: @EvanMorrison that has worked! Never would've thought of that in all honesty. Now to fix the `[Object] [Object]` I'm thrown with whatever text in the URL ;) Thanks again!